# Tab mismatch issue in primereact

Tags: reactjs, primereact

The code below is a form in my react app which shows up when a user edits a record from a data table - datatable and edit part is not shown here as it's not relevant.

**Explanation of Tab Mismatch issue :**

As soon as the below page loads, I see the following tabs (image below) on the UI with `Tab1` highlighted:

[image]

The network tab of my browser shows the following web service call:

**First webservice call for `Tab1`:**

```
https://myserver.com/MyServices/api/assets/search/getAssetCategories?requestId=100&assetCategoryId=0
```

Similarly, when I click `Tab 2`, the web service call is :

**Second webservice call for `Tab2`:**

```
https://myserver.com/MyServices/api/assets/search/getAssetCategories?requestId=100&assetCategoryId=1
```

And with `Tab 3`, it's :

**Third webservice call for `Tab3`:**

```
https://myserver.com/MyServices/api/assets/search/getAssetCategories?requestId=100&assetCategoryId=2
```

As you can see, since I am sending the value of `selectedTabIndex` for the parameter `assetCategoryId` in my webservice call in the `useEffect` function and value of `event.index` for the parameter `assetCategoryId` inside `onTabSelected` function.  , the `Tab1` is highlighted because of `0` value of `selectedTabIndex` inside `useEffect` function and hence the

```
//Inside useEffect function     
params: { assetCategoryId: selectedTabIndex } 
//Inside onTabSelected function
params: {assetCategoryId: event.index}
```

However, since I have the following available:

```
  const assetCategories = JSON.parse('[{"id":1,"value":"Tab 1"},{"id":2,"value":"Tab 2"},{"id":3,"value":"Tab 3"}]');
```

**Question 1**.

Inside `useEffect` function, I want to send first value of the `id` field to the `assetCategoryId` parameter instead of the selectedTabIndex while calling the webservice call. Is it possible to do this? I mean I did like this `assetCategores[0].id` and it worked but is this a good way to achieve this?

**Question 2**.

I want to keep the `activeIndex` value based on the first id parameter, which is `1` in my case and not based on `selectedTabIndex` like it is in my code now:

```
  <TabView   id='AssetsTabView' activeIndex={selectedTabIndex}
```

One another issue which could arise is when the values of `id` could be like this and I would still want to display `Tab1` , `Tab2` and `Tab3` properly:

```
const assetCategories = JSON.parse('[{"id":34,"value":"Tab 1"},{"id":66,"value":"Tab 2"},{"id":999,"value":"Tab 3"}]');
```

**My complete code below:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { Form,  withFormik} from 'formik';
    import {Button} from '@material-ui/core'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import {TabPanel, TabView} from "primereact/tabview";
        
    const RequestForm = (props) => {
        const {values, setFieldValue, touched, errors, isSubmitting, handleReset, handleChange} = props;
        const [selectedTabIndex, setSelectedTabIndex] = useState(0);
       
     useEffect(() => {
         if(props.dataRequest){
              let editeddataRequestId = props.dataRequest.requestId;
                    axios
                   .get('api/assets/search/getAssetCategories?requestId='+editeddataRequestId, {
                        params: {
                            assetCategoryId: selectedTabIndex
                        }
                    }).then(response => {
                                 
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    
        }//end if of props.dataRequest
    
     
    }, []);
    
     var onTabSelected = (event) => {
            (event.index) ? setSelectedTabIndex(event.index) : null
          
            if(props.dataRequest){
                let editeddataRequestId = props.dataRequest.requestId;
              
                    axios
                        .get('api/assets/search/getAssetCategories?requestId='+editeddataRequestId, {    
                            params: {
                                assetCategoryId: event.index
                            }
                        }).then(response => {
                                         
                    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
            }      
    
            
        };
       const assetCategories = JSON.parse('[{"id":1,"value":"Tab 1"},{"id":2,"value":"Tab 2"},{"id":3,"value":"Tab 3"}]');
    
      const DynamicTabView = ({ activeIndex, onTabChange }) => (
            <div style={{width: 'max-content', whiteSpace: 'nowrap', marginLeft: 'auto', marginRight: 'auto'}}>
                <TabView   id='AssetsTabView' activeIndex={selectedTabIndex}
                          onTabChange={(e) => setSelectedTabIndex(e.index), (e) => onTabSelected(e)}>
                            
                    {assetCategories.map((item, i) =>
                        <TabPanel  key={i} header={item.value}></TabPanel>
                    )}
                </TabView>
            </div>
        );
    
    return (
            <div>
                 <Form className="form-column-3">
                      <DynamicTabView activeIndex={selectedTabIndex} onTabChange={(e) => {setSelectedTabIndex(e.index), () => { this.onTabSelected(e) }}}/>                
                      <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={props.onCancel} style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Cancel</Button>
                   </Form>
              
            </div>
        )
    
    };
    
    export const DataRequestEnhancedFormEdw = withFormik({
            mapPropsToValues: props => {
               return {}
            },
    })(RequestForm)
```